# dynamic text - URL changes Keywords

Tags: php, url, dynamic

Can not find exact answer for this question. I'm sure it's somewhere there. But technique may be so old that I can not find/get it.

Basically I want URL to change some parts of my content.
http:// www.somewebsite.com/?area=london

So some parts of web page will change city name to "london"

Exactly like one guy did here:
http://seo.carlreed.co.uk/ppc-example/?area=london
http://seo.carlreed.co.uk/ppc-example/?area=manchester

It's all the same website but changes.

Thank you so much for help!
All the best!
Chris

Comment: If it's on html page, should I use <?php $_GET['area'] ?> every time I want to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Yep,

```
$area = $_GET['area'];
```

This will to retrieve the value from your URL.  Then you can use it as needed to change your content.

Note: if at any point you need to put $area into a database, don't forget to sanitize the value to prevent attacks on your database.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

on your page

```
if(isset($_GET['area'])){

    $area = $_GET['area'];

//do what ever you want to $area variable


}
```

when you do a query, make sure you clean first the variable with escape string or use parameters to do the query.